# How to make a threading race situation

Tags: c#, multithreading

For some reasons, I want to create a race problem with 2 threads. I thought that the race problem was caused when 2 threads that didn't lock the shared resource were running at the same time... which is what I'm trying to code. But the output is correct, and I want it to be wrong.

My shared resource is a static variable in a static class.

The problem is that it correctly outputs 1200. I know it sounds weird but I am trying to understand how to create/solve that kind of problem.

In my book, concepts of programming languages, it talks theoretically about such a problem.

The question is : **How do I make it so this code produce random problems caused by my two threads accessing the same shared resource ?**

```
public static class BankAccount
{
    public static int solde = 0;

}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BankAccount.solde = 1000;

        Thread t = new Thread(up);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(down);


        t.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t.Join();
        t2.Join();


        Console.Write(BankAccount.solde);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void up()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            BankAccount.solde++;
        }
    }

    static void down()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            BankAccount.solde--;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that's weird, are you sure you run in *release* and *outside the debugger* ? because the JIT needs to modify this code (put variables in registers) so that it fails. Just like that it will do the load/stores at each instruction and it doesn't fail thanks to MESI.

Comment: @v.oddou interesting, but it still works fine in release mode.

Comment: This is a great question. It illustrates the futility of using testing to show the absence of race conditions. I use essentially the same example when I teach, and wrote a blog post on it a few years ago. http://sourcephile.blogspot.ca/2009/04/difficulty-of-testing-concurrent-code.html

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell interesting post very similar to my situation, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* race, you're just not running it enough times.

Try this main method instead.

It tries repeatedly and shows you when it fails, and how many runs it took to get a failure:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var runCount = 0;
    do
    {
        BankAccount.solde = 1000;
        runCount++;
        Thread t = new Thread(up);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(down);

        t.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t.Join();
        t2.Join();
    } 
    while (BankAccount.solde == 1200);


    Console.Write(BankAccount.solde + ": Run: " + runCount);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Output for me in debugger:

```
1201: Run: 36
```

Running in release mode with optimizations, it rarely races (because the code in the each thread runs so fast, thread 1 normally finishes before thread 2 even starts), but it still happens occasionally:

```
1414: Run: 168804
```

If you want it to race **much more frequently**, change your 'up' loop to iterate 50000 times, and your 'down' loop to iterate 49800 times.

Then you get crazy results like this (release mode, outside debugger):

```
-1198: Run: 12
```

This most likely happens when the decrements interleave persistently with the increments, such that in many cases, only the decrements are actually applied to the variable.

Comment: 36 runs is impressive, my computer hardly goes over 3.

Comment: Good. I guess that will do it... but for some reason, I though that when 2 thread accessed the same shared resource, my computer would start burning. Seriously I though that the count would be really off, I saw that on a Java tutorial, his variable actually didn't went up at all.

Comment: while you're at it, you could also mention in your book that if you have parallel workers modifying (different) values in an array of variables, if the compiler outputs the load/store at each assignment then the performance plummets because the hardware serializes access to the whole array (MESI). A cache line is 128 bytes so you would need more than 16 cores to start to have parallelization. The fix is to leave 128 bytes padding gaps in the array between each variable.

Comment: As you can see (edit above), if you change the number of iterations so that it races more often, the count CAN be really off.

Comment: @Dave: you should accept that as the answer, it really fixes your demo by showing that the invariant is broken because the program terminates. Also the explanation will be hard to write because C# is compiled, then interpreted, then mutated by JIT, then the CPU mutates the machine code again (OOO execution) and so many issues related to standard (relative to virtual machine), memory fences, compiler fences and x86 specification strong observable memory order guarantees (versus looser memory ordering specs like powerPC)...

Comment: @Dave There is no way to create a *guaranteed* race condition, or one where the work of one thread *exactly* counterbalances the work of the other. If that was the case, it wouldn't be a race condition at all, since you would have to synchronise the threads correctly. You wouldn't be seeing a result dependent on which thread randomly wins the "race" to reach a particular block of code.

Comment: I think the initialization or `.solde` should be 1200. Sadly Stackexchange does not permit 1 character edits.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell: Nope, it should be 1000. It's meant to go up N times, and go down (N-200) times. The end result should be 1200 if there was no racing.

Answer (score 0):

Do more of something more complicated; your critical sections are very small, which reduces the probability getting a bad interleaving, and the more times you enter them, the more likely you'll get a 'problem'.

Comment: Since the `++` and `--` operators use a *read, modify, write* cycle they can overlap quite frequently on non-interlocked operations.  That's why Baldrick's code ever exits :)

Comment: Oh and the scheduler doesn't wait for that *RMW* cycle to complete, so the `up` thread can get a value, then have to wait while the `down` thread runs a few times... then the `up` thread writes its result back, obliterating everything the `down` thread did.

Comment: @Corey I'm not sure what you mean by "Baldrick's code never exits". The only circumstance where Baldrick's code will never exit is if it fails to create a race condition between the threads in an infinite number of attempts, which has zero probability.

Comment: @Asad Read again... "That's why Baldrick's code **ever** exits".

Comment: @Corey Whoops. Sorry about that.